# Transit Visa in Abu Dhabi

Tags: visas, transit, albanian-citizens

I am an Albanian citizens and i have a connecting flight in Abu Dhabi for about 3.5 hours.
Do I need a transit visa if i stay inside the airport?

Answer (score 2):

Per the [airport site](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/transit-information/less-than-4-hours.aspx):

> Will I need a UAE visa?
>
> You won’t require a UAE transit visa if you are staying in the airport for a period of four hours or less.

Comment: There is an interesting inconsistency, the airport site says four hours as you rightly point out but the [Etihad](https://www.etihad.com/en-fr/before-you-fly/visas/) site now says eight hours or less. Will try and find out why.